# Jquery show and hide not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a page with an image that stays in place for a certain amount of time, then is replaced by an `h3`.

jquery:

```
 $('#stories-dropdown h3').hide();
   $('#stories-dropdown img').delay(4000).hide();
   $('#stories-dropdown h3').delay(5000).show();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stories-dropdown" class="dropdown">


<h3 id="h3">Sorry, we have no stories to show you now. Try again later.</h3>
<img src="pics/loding.gif" width="100px" id="img">
</div>
```

The `h3` isn't hid, and neither is the image. This code is bound to a `.click()` function.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tv63avkz/3/)

Comment: In the fiddle you haven't inlcuded jQuery library

Comment: Without any values, e.g. `.hide(500)`, both show and hide do not animate and just modify the display property. If you pass values then they will animate and you can use `.delay()` with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is, your usage of delay is wrong as it will work only with methods that uses queue based execution

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#stories-dropdown h3').hide().stop(true).delay(4000).queue(function() {
    $(this).show();
  })
  $('#stories-dropdown img').show().stop(true).delay(4000).queue(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  })
})
```

```css
#stories-dropdown h3,
#stories-dropdown img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Test</button>
<div id="stories-dropdown" class="dropdown">
  <h3 id="h3">Sorry, we have no stories to show you now. Try again later.</h3>
  <img src="http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/Misc/loding2.gif" width="100px" id="img" />
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8qfufcy3/)

---

Or as @j08691 suggested - if you are ok with a minor animation

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#stories-dropdown h3').hide().stop(true).delay(4000).show(1)
    $('#stories-dropdown img').show().stop(true).delay(5000).hide(1)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8qfufcy3/4/)

Comment: Or you could just pass values to show and hide, ex `.hide(500)`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tv63avkz/4/